# Bounce notifications for SES identity

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-ses

Here's a snippet of my CDK TypeScript code that creates an SES identity and SNS topic:

```
  toolsAccountSES = new EmailIdentity(this, 'ToolsSESidentity', {
    identity: Identity.publicHostedZone(hostedZone),
  });

  // setting up bounce notifications
  const bounceTopic = new Topic(this, `ses-bounce-${props.branchName}`, {
    topicName: `ses-bounce-${props.branchName}`,
    displayName: `SES bounce notifications for ${props.branchName}`,
  });

  bounceTopic.addSubscription(new EmailSubscription(bounceEmail))
```

Is there a way to add this topic to the identity to receive bounce notifications? I couldn't find a way to do this in CDK

UPDATE: Code for attempted solution

I've created a construct that creates the configuration set

```
export class sesConfig extends Construct {
  public configurationSet: ConfigurationSet;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);

    const bounceTopic = new Topic(this, 'bounce-topic');
    bounceTopic.addSubscription(new EmailSubscription(bounceEmail));

    this.configurationSet = new ConfigurationSet(this, 'ses-config');

    this.configurationSet.addEventDestination('bounce-destination', {
      destination: EventDestination.snsTopic(bounceTopic),
      events: [EmailSendingEvent.BOUNCE],
    });
;
  }
}
```

And I pass it to the constructor when creating the email identity

```
    new EmailIdentity(scope, 'SubdomainIdentity', {
      identity: Identity.publicHostedZone(hostedZone),
      configurationSet: new sesConfig(scope, 'ses-config').configurationSet, 
    });
```

Email identity is created, and so is the SNS topic, but when I look at the identity in the console - no notification is set

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [configurationSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ses.EmailIdentity.html#configurationset) prop to your `EmailIdentity` construct.  A [Configuration Set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/using-configuration-sets.html) is a group of rules that are applied to an identity.  Instatiate a [ConfigurationSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ses.ConfigurationSet.html) construct.  Add a [ConfigurationSetEventDestination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ses.ConfigurationSetEventDestination.html) with the `addEventDestination` method.  Configure your destination to use your SNS topic for the desired [events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ses.EmailSendingEvent.html) (like `BOUNCE` or `COMPLAINT`).

See also the CloudFormation docs for [AWS::SES::ConfigurationSet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ses-configurationset.html) and [AWS::SES::ConfigurationSetEventDestination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ses-configurationseteventdestination.html). The AWS blog post [Amazon SES – Set up notifications for bounces and complaints](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/amazon-ses-set-up-notifications-for-bounces-and-complaints/) discusses Configuration Sets.

Comment: That was it, thanks!